# How to use only half of imagenet train set during iterations using code Tensorflow provided?

Tags: python, tensorflow, imagenet

The [code](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/b3ef7ae9d3c1f6cfc9a202255ed2aa6b9d2aa791/research/inception/inception/data) is provided by Tensorflow, and this is how to get ImageNet TFrecord file when trianing:

```
import tensorflow as tf       
import imagenet_data
import image_processing

imagenet_data_train = imagenet_data.ImagenetData('train')
train_images, train_labels =  image_processing.inputs(imagenet_data_train, batch_size=256, num_preprocess_threads=16)

coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = []
for qr in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.QUEUE_RUNNERS):
   threads.extend(qr.create_threads(sess, coord=coord, daemon=True, start=True))


with tf.Session() as sess:      

    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    try:
        for i in range(1000):    
            image_batch, label_batch = sess.run([train_images, train_labels ])

    finally:
            coord.request_stop()
            coord.join(threads)
```

And now I just want to use a half of training data(could be the first 0.6 million data in Tfreocd file) to iterate during training, what shoul I set?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by modifying the class ImagenetData`train_set_number_rate` with adding an extra parameter `train_set_number_rate` and modifyting the method `data_files`, which control the list of filename to pass to next function.

Notice that in this way, I have to use function `distorted_inputs` instead of `inputs` to make sure same part of train set are used in different models fine-tuned.(This may causes some bad effection on vali performance. But since I have used `inputs` to train the original networks, `inputs` have to be used to make sure the correctness of comparision.)

```
 class ImagenetData(Dataset):

     def __init__(self, subset, train_set_number_rate = None):
        super(ImagenetData, self).__init__('ImageNet', subset)
        self.train_set_number_rate = train_set_number_rate
     def data_files(self):
        """Returns a python list of all (sharded) data subset files.

        Returns:
          python list of all (sharded) data set files.
        Raises:
          ValueError: if there are not data_files matching the subset.
        """
        tf_record_pattern = os.path.join(data_dir, '%s-*' % self.subset)
        data_files = tf.gfile.Glob(tf_record_pattern)
        if self.subset=='validation':
            assert(self.train_set_number_rate==None)
        elif self.subset=='train':
            if self.train_set_number_rate!=None:
                data_files = data_files[0:round(len(data_files)*self.train_set_number_rate)]
        if not data_files:
            print('No files found for dataset %s/%s at %s' % (self.name,
                                                              self.subset,
                                                              data_dir))

            self.download_message()
            exit(-1)
        return data_files
```